# Create Parallax Full Width Background Scrolling with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, scroll, parallax

I am getting more and more desperate. I want to use the same scrolling parallax effect as http://wedgeandlever.com, but I really can't find any way to do so. I already tried implementing a standalone version and plugins with and without "Visual Composer" - I even tried a paid one and all of the Visual Composer Plugins do not show any image at all.

I would be really thankful and happy if someone could point me something as close as possible to the effect wedgeandlever has implemented.

Thanks in advance and kind regards
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a list](https://colorlib.com/wp/parallax-wordpress-themes/) of a bunch of different parallax with scroll themes. You could experiment with those.

Not sure if you're willing to get your hands dirty, but [this](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) is an implementation of parallax with scroll. You could possibly modify a theme on your own.